# CSS - set height of two floated div matching first div's height

Tags: html, css

I have this sample code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        [ some contents...]
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="inner">
            [ some templates... ]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have two divs where I want `#right` div with height settled fixed to `#left` height even in `#inner` there's a longer content where I can show a vertical scrollbar...

How I could do that? I am asking because I know I can set as table-cell but with this if `#inner` has longer content, then first div would increase height to match `#inner` div's height.

Comment: I don't see #first in your code.

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/V5mWr/ ?

Comment: hello abhitalks, no, because first div has flexible height depending to the content and plus divs #left and #right has to be floated...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#container {min-height: 100px; background-color: beige;}
#right {float: right; position: relative; max-width: 200px;}
#inner {position: relative; height: 100px; overflow: auto;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right">
        <div id="inner">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        [ some contents...]
    </div>
</div>
```

Code is also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/c29t7/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/24rQZ/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        [ some contents...]
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        [ some more contents...]
        <div id="right">
            [ some contents...]
            <div id="inner">
               [ some templates... ]
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />                    
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                [ some more templates...]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#right {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:75%; /*or whatever looks nice*/

    background:#00ff00;
}
#inner {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    width:75%; /*or whatever looks nice*/
}
```

EDIT: I think this is what you are looking for, I had to put the `#right` inside the `#left`

Comment: No, as I said to abhitalks, #left doesn't have fixed height and #right simply follows #left's height and #inner if taller than its parent then show vertical scrollbar...

Comment: @Luigino If that is your requirement, then you should use JavaScript to fix the height of 'right' equal to the height of 'left'.

This could be done something like this **document.getElementById('right').offsetHeight=document.getElementById('left').offsetHeight**

Comment: Azeez I think programmatically is probably the best way but I tried to add in the $(document).ready(function() { [...] $("#wrapper-outer").bind('resize', function(e) { $('#widget-container').height($('#wrapper').height()-$('#header-button').height()); }); }); but it doesn't catch resize even if I see that div changes physically height (checked with chrome's element inspect)...maybe is there a different resize?